# How to print out a negative number represented by an array

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

I'm just starting to learn Java, and I want to try to represent big negative numbers using arrays.

Let's say I have an array

```
[-2, 0, -5] and this represents the number -502
```

I've tried using a StringBuilder, but it prints out

```
-50-2
```

This is my code as of right now. Is there a way to make it so I can append the first negative, and then skip the rest of the negatives when I am building a new String?

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int x = arr.length-1; x>=0; x--){
        sb.append(arr[x]);
    }
    String check = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(check);
```

Comment: How does `[-2, 0, -5]` represent `-502`? What is the meaning of `-`?

Comment: why does [-2, 0, -5] represent -502? what about [-2, 0, 5] and [2, 0, -5]?

Comment: I am just building it from the last --> first

Comment: Still you must explain the meaning of `-`. How are they to be 'combined'

Comment: yeah, but its not about the order of digits, its about the sign. need a little bit more information on how those 3 cases are different or equal.

Comment: If you build it from last to first, maybe it should be [2,0,-5] ?

Comment: It's part of a bigger problem, but basically I took a number like -502 and added it to an array by modding it by 10.

Comment: i see, well like @jhamon said, you should just keep the sign on the last one  OR  append the absolute value and add a negative sign IF and only IF you are only using that method to show negative values only. (since it will add the negative sign on positives too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize the string buffer with the last character (with appropriate sign) and then simply ignore the signs for the rest.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(arr[length-1]);

for (int x = arr.length-2; x>=0; x--) {
    sb.append(Math.abs(arr[x]));
}
String check = sb.toString();
System.out.println(check);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a minus at the beginning of the string and use `Math.abs(arr[x])` in appending.

It should look like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("-");
for(int x = arr.length-1; x>=0; x--){
   sb.append(Math.abs(arr[x]));
}
String check = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Your question is unclear, but I think this does what you want:

```
if(x == arr.length-1 || x > 0)
    sb.append(arr[x]);
else
    sb.append(-arr[x]);
```

`-` cancels itself out. `-(-5)` is just 5.

Alternatively: (this might or might not be easier to understand for you)

```
if(x == arr.length-1)
    sb.append(arr[x]);
else
    sb.append(Math.abs(arr[x]));
```

`Math.abs` is a method that makes sure a number isn't negative - if the number you give it is positive or zero, it returns it. If the number you give it is negative, it returns the positive version.

Alternatively:

```
sb.append((x == arr.length - 1) ? arr[x] : Math.abs(arr[x]));
```

This is just "shorthand" for the previous suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      Integer[] arr = new Integer[10];        
      if(arr[arr.length-1]<0)
          sb.append("-");
      for(int x = arr.length-1; x>=0; x--){
            sb.append(Math.abs(arr[x]));              
      }
      String check = sb.toString();
      System.out.println(check);
```

Answer (score 0):

To "skip the remaining negatives" with this case, take the first negative number "as is" and take the absolute value of the remaining negative numbers before appending them. Use a call to `Math.abs(arr[x])` to take the absolute value. This way the string builder would look at your array, take the -5, and then see "02" as it appends the following integers.

Now if the requirement were that you wanted the biggest negative number with a possibly longer array, say [-5, -3, 2, 6] and you want it to return -5632... Start by taking the smallest negative number (-5) as the first number to append, and you could make a new array with the absolute value of all remaining values of the original array. Then append by progressively taking the maximum unused value of the array.